# Equation exceeds the width of text size.. [optidef package]

Tags: align

My code is

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}

\newcommand{\bx}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol x}}}
\newcommand{\bX}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol X}}}
\newcommand{\bp}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol p}}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol R}}}

\begin{document}
zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz 
\begin{mini!}|l|[2]
    {\bx_i : i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}}
    {f(\bx_i)}
    {\label{eq:optimizationProblem}}{}
    \addConstraint{\max_{k=1,\ldots,\lvert\bp_v\rvert-1} d\big(\bp_v(k), \bp_v(k+1)\big)}{\le d_0,~\forall v\in\{1,\ldots,M\}}{}
\end{mini!}
zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz 
\end{document}
```

My result is
[image: img]

As you see, the constraint equation exceeds its own range.
How can I deal with this problem? T.T
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{bm}` after `amsmath` and change the definitions for the bold letters into `\newcommand{\bx}{\bm{x}}`. You don't need `\ensuremath`, which only adds some overhead at each call; if you need the letter in text, just type `$\bx$`.

Comment: Thank you, to be honest, I do not understand well about this presetting codes (before main domument function). Actually I copied "\newcommand{\bx}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol x}}}" from other user's document. :()

Comment: Now, I changed my code as you recommend (using bm package). Thank you :)

Comment: May I ask more things? how to change the following codes (instead of boldsymbol, mathbf) ? \newcommand{\x}{\ensuremath{{\mathbf x}}}

Comment: You don't need `\ensuremath`, to begin with. The correct syntax would be `\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}`. The commands `\boldsymbol`, `\bm` and `\mathbf` all take an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}

\newcommand{\bx}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol x}}}
\newcommand{\bX}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol X}}}
\newcommand{\bp}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol p}}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol R}}}

\begin{document}

zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz
\begin{mini!}|l|[2]
    {\mathclap{\strut \bx_i : i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}}}
    {f(\bx_i)}
    {\label{eq:optimizationProblem}}{}
    \addConstraint{\smashoperator{\max}_k d\bigl(\bp_v(k), \bp_v(k+1)\bigr)}{\begin{aligned}[t]\le d_0,\\~\mathllap{\forall v\in\{1,\ldots,M\}}\end{aligned}}{}
\end{mini!}
zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but may I ask what the smashoperator is?

Comment: Oh, no. I found that smashoperator at mathtools.pdf~ Thank you :)

Comment: @Danny_Kim: Sorry for seeing your question  so late. As you've probably found out, it's for neutralising wide indices/exponents under/over an operator.